# How to set delay for display tooltip on birt chart for long time?

Tags: tooltip, birt

I'm using birt to create report chart, I want to show tooltip on chart. How to set delays to display tooltip for long time ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 is the best option, but I included option 2 as informational guess about when a parameter or setting is not available via the easy way (1)

1. It is in the XML of the report, not displayed as an option, but defaults it to 200.  Just edit in the XML Source view.

   ```
    <Triggers>
       <Condition>onmouseover</Condition>
       <Action>
         <Type>Show_Tooltip</Type>
         <Value xsi:type="attribute:TooltipValue">
           <Text>adsfasdf</Text>
           <Delay>200</Delay>
         </Value>
       </Action>
     </Triggers>
   ```
2. Here is the java class, I believe you can call that from a custom object or something, I have not done a lot of that.
   http://www.birt-exchange.org/documentation/BIRT_231/ChartJavadoc/chart/api/org/eclipse/birt/chart/model/attribute/TooltipValue.html